# How to Set Banner-Like Background Image With CSS

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have been looking at a lot of the source code for sites and can't seem to figure this out. I want to have an image that's in the background, behind everything. I don't, however, want the entire background to be that image; I only want it towards the top kinda like a banner of sorts. Some examples can be found at http://www.animefreak.tv/, and http://us.battle.net/wow/en/. Right now I have a textured background with:

```
body   
{

background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHhtbG5zOnhsaW5rPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5L3hsaW5rIiB3aWR0aD0iNiIgaGVpZ2h0PSI2Ij4KPHJlY3Qgd2lkdGg9IjYiIGhlaWdodD0iNiIgZmlsbD0iI2VlZWVlZSI+PC9yZWN0Pgo8ZyBpZD0iYyI+CjxyZWN0IHdpZHRoPSIzIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjMiIGZpbGw9IiNlNmU2ZTYiPjwvcmVjdD4KPHJlY3QgeT0iMSIgd2lkdGg9IjMiIGhlaWdodD0iMiIgZmlsbD0iI2Q4ZDhkOCI+PC9yZWN0Pgo8L2c+Cjx1c2UgeGxpbms6aHJlZj0iI2MiIHg9IjMiIHk9IjMiPjwvdXNlPgo8L3N2Zz4=");

font-size: .80em;

font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
margin: 0px;

padding: 0px;

color: #696969;

}
```

Any image I try to put in my CSS simply appears above the main page div of my site, when I want it to appear behind like in the given examples. I put a

```
 <div class = "topb">

 </div>
```

at the top of my MasterPage and then used

```
.topb
{
height: 243px;margin: 0px;padding: 0px;overflow: hidden;
background:  url(/images/test2.jpg) no-repeat top center;
background-image:url(/images/test2.jpg);
}
```

in my CSS as a test, but I am obviously new to CSS and HTML development. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this.

CSS3 allows you to have multiple background images. You can do this:

```
body {
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: url(texture.png), url(banner.png);
  background-position: center center, center top;
  background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
}
```

Or you can add a wrapper `div` right after the `<body>` that holds all of the content and add your banner background image to that.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="Wrapper">
  <!-- The rest of your site's content -->
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: #000 url(texture.png) repeat center center;
}
#Wrapper {
  background: url(banner.png) no-repeat center top;
}
```

If you want to add some spacing at the top so your content doesn't cover the banner, simply add some padding like so:

```
#Wrapper { padding-top: 240px; }
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!! I kept trying to add div's outside 'body' ><; this is way simpler than I thought it would be :)

Comment: No problem. All of your content should always go inside of the `<body>` :-)